# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "refrán" y "proverbio"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

Las dos palabras me parecen iguales. Tampoco podía encontrar una diferencia saliente en el diccionario. ¿Existe alguna diferencia?

Comment: La RAE tira que son sinónimos. ¿No basta con eso?

Comment: @Ustanak Bueno. Pienso que siempre existen algunas diferencias entre dos palabras aunque sean sinónimos. Quizás eso no sea verdad.

Comment: Pregunta relacionada: [¿Qué diferencia hay entre locución, frase hecha, refrán y proverbio?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21540/5481). La pregunta enlazada es mucho más amplia que esta, pero algunas de las respuestas dadas allí pueden ser relevantes para esta pregunta.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/444372/112436

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sin consultar la RAE u otro diccionario oficial diría que, aunque ambos términos puedan ser considerados sinónimos, la **connotación** de cada uno sería:

- refrán: es un dicho **popular** y coloquial, o consejo sobre cualquier cosa, banal o importante. Suele rimar, para hacerlo más "pegadizo" o fácil de recordar.
- proverbio: es un poco más serio que el refrán. No suele dar consejo sobre cosas banales, sino de contenido más "moral" o sobre "ética". De hecho creo que "Proverbios" es uno de los libros de la Biblia.

Por ejemplo

> Marzo ventoso y abril lluvioso sacan a mayo florido y hermoso.

Eso es un refrán. Rima y es fácil de recordar. Habla sobre el tiempo atmosférico, recordándote que en cada mes el tiempo es como es y que si en abril llueve mucho ya en mayo tendrás buen tiempo.

Un proverbio es algo más serio que eso. Es como para dar un sermón, amonestar o enseñar de una forma menos coloquial y más severa que el refrán.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proverbio) lo confirma: `En la lengua española, la denominación refrán ha conocido una gran difusión hasta el punto de arrinconar a proverbio que se asocia a una paremia culta como los proverbios bíblicos, frente al refrán, paremia popular o popularizada.`

Comment: Dice la wiki en "frase hecha": _El proverbio se diferencia del refrán en la forma, ya que mientras éste es de tono jocoso y se lo expresa con palabras comunes y a veces groseras, aquel está expresado de una manera más seria y grave_. [Fundéu](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/aforismo-proverbio-y-refran-599/) abre el debate otra vez diciendo que _la única diferencia es que el aforismo y el proverbio son cortos y el refrán no tiene por qué serlo_. Pero me quedo con _el refrán para la expresión hablada y el proverbio para la erudición moral_ que encontré por ahí.

Comment: Las connotaciones que yo tenía en mente van por lo que indicáis. El refrán relacionado con la tradición oral y más informal. El proverbio mas relacionado con lo escrito, lo erudito y con reflexiones más profundas.