# ¿Es lo mismo un modismo que una frase idiomática? ¿Y una expresión fija?

Tags: expresiones

Al hilo de la publicación en Meta [¡Ordenemos las etiquetas!](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2495/1674) estoy mirando qué conceptos son equivalentes.

De entre ellos, uno que me pica bastante la curiosidad es:

- modismos
- frases idiomáticas
- expresión
- idiomático
- expresiones fijas

El debate sobre las etiquetas está ceñido al ámbito de Meta, pero gramáticamente, ¿es lo mismo *modismo* y *frase idiomática*? Entiendo que *frase idiomática* viene del inglés *idiom*, cuya traducción es *modismo* [según WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=idiom). ¿Es así en todos los casos?

En su momento vimos que [refrán y proverbio son diferentes](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17128/1674) pese a que la RAE indica que son sinónimos. No sé si ocurre lo mismo aquí.

En cuanto a la relación del *[modismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PUlqsDD)* con *[expresión](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HL12F3g)*, veo que un modismo no deja de ser un tipo de expresión; en concreto, una expresión fija. Esto me lleva a ver que [las expresiones fijas son](http://elies.rediris.es/elies6/cap2353.htm):

- locuciones
- expresiones idiomáticas
- modismos

Lo que tira un poco por tierra el hecho de que expresión/frase idiomática sea sinónimo de modismo.

Comment: En mi opinión es todo lo mismo, salvo que se tiende a decir _frase hecha_ o _frase idiomática_ cuando la expresión fija es más larga o tiene verbo. Todas son _modismos_. _Expresiones_ y _locuciones_ abarcan mucho más; no las usaría como etiquetas.

Comment: @angus gracias por tu aportación, me parece muy convincente. Veo que hay quien [dice](https://lenguajeyotrasluces.wordpress.com/2015/04/28/modismos-y-frases-hechas-dele-b2/) que una frase hecha tiene verbo, mientras que el modismo no.

Comment: Creo que es mayormente una cuestión de opiniones. Esa distinción no la respetan ni siquiera la "Lista de frases hechas" y el "Manual de modismos" a los que enlaza en la página. De todas maneras, supongo que SSE puede tomar la decisión editorial de distinguir entre _frases hechas_ y _modismos_ para organizar mejor las etiquetas, si es necesario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Me responde la RAE [vía Twitter](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/762537004081016832) que sí, modismo y expresión idiomática son lo mismo:

> @fedorqui #RAEconsultas Como expresión fija cuyo significado no se
>   deduce de las palabras que la forman se usan MODISMO y EXPRESIÓN
>   IDIOMÁTICA.

Y posteriormente añade que *expresión idiomática* y *frase idiomática* son expresiones sinónimas.

Por tanto, estos tres conceptos son equivalentes:

- Modismo
- Expresión idiomática
- Frase idiomática