# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre locución, frase hecha, refrán y proverbio?

Tags: gramática, locuciones, refranes, proverbios

Leía hace poco un manual de catalán en el que se destacaba la diferencia entre estos tres grupos gramaticales:

> - La **locución** es una parte de la oración que substituye un nombre, un adjetivo, un adverbio, una conjunción o una preposición y que hace la función de estas partículas.
> - La **frase hecha** es una oración completa, con sujeto y predicado, y sustituye una locución verbal.
> - El **refrán** o **proverbio** es una citación invariable que a menudo aparece después de dos puntos o entrecomillado (no admite cambios verbales de tiempo, ni la adición de cuantitativos o diminutivos, ni tampoco ninguna variación formal).

Esto aplica al catalán, pero no sé si también el castellano. Mirando en el DLE observo:

> [**locución**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NYSj8PH)
>   3. f. Gram. Grupo de palabras que funcionan como una sola pieza léxica con un sentido unitario y cierto grado de fijación formal.
>   4. f. Gram. Combinación fija de varios vocablos que funciona como una determinada clase de palabras.
>
> [**frase hecha**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IPhICME)
>   1. f. frase que es de uso común y expresa una sentencia a modo de proverbio. *En el medio está la virtud. Nunca segundas partes fueron buenas.*
>   2. f. frase que, en sentido figurado y con forma inalterable, es de uso común y no incluye sentencia alguna. *¡Aquí fue Troya! Como anillo al dedo.*
>
> [**refrán**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VesRhX7)
>   1. m. Dicho agudo y sentencioso de uso común.
>
> [**proverbio**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UTwvbOV)
>   1. m. Sentencia, adagio o refrán.

Siguiendo los vínculos dados en estas definiciones damos con:

> [**dicho, cha**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DgXmXNM)
>   2. m. Palabra o conjunto de palabras con que se expresa oralmente un concepto cabal. Dicho agudo, oportuno, intempestivo, malicioso.
>
> [**adagio**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0gbw6xc)
>   1. m. Sentencia breve y, la mayoría de las veces, moral.
>
> [**sentencia**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xb6DGYA)
>   5. f. Ling. Oración gramatical.

Por lo que parece que sí encaja, con el matiz de que según los ejemplos de *frase hecha*, estas tampoco aceptarían cambios verbales de tiempo ni otro tipo.

Resumiendo: ¿cuál sería la jerarquía de estas construcciones gramaticales?

Comment: Pregunta relacionada: [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre “refrán” y “proverbio”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17128/5481), que es menos amplia que esta. Respuestas de esta pregunta serán relevantes para la pregunta enlazada.

Comment: Qué bien visto, @Diego muchas gracias por indicarlo. Claramente, estamos ante un sudoku gramatical que también incluye [¿Es lo mismo un modismo que una frase idiomática? ¿Y una expresión fija?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17650/1674)

Comment: Tienes razón. Ahora que la veo me doy cuenta de que esa pregunta me salió también entre los resultados de búsqueda y mi cerebro no la procesó. La debí de confundir con esta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes que nada, creo que debemos hacer una diferenciación elemental: las frases son sólo grupos de palabras, y las oraciones tienen sujeto y predicado. En general las locuciones y las frases hechas e idiomáticas serán frases, mientras que los dichos, refranes y proverbios serán oraciones.

La única definición incluida en la pregunta que me resulta a todas luces clara es la de “locución”, definida como un conjunto de palabras que funciona como la palabra que la califica: la locución preposicional funciona como una preposición, la locución adverbial como un adverbio, la locución conjuntiva como una conjunción. Así, “de acuerdo con” es una locución preposicional equivalente a la preposición “según”.

“Frases hechas” y “frases idiomáticas” son términos bastante similares, atribuibles a combinaciones de palabras que se consideran “caprichosas” en el sentido de que no siguen las reglas habituales de conformación de frases. Así, decimos que estamos **al sol** o **a la sombra**, pero que seguimos a alguien **a sol y a sombra**. La ausencia del artículo delante de “sol” y de “sombra” es atípica y hace que la frase “seguir a alguien a sol y a sombra” sea hecha o idiomática (equivalente a las *set phrases* o *idioms* del inglés).

En cuando a los dichos, refranes y proverbios, me parece que este orden justamente refleja su gradual complejidad semántica: los dichos y refranes tienden a ser más simples, propios del saber popular, y los proverbios pueden ser más complejos, por su origen más literario y su selección de palabras más refinadas.

(Con más tiempo, me gustaría completar la respuesta con más ejemplos.)

Comment: Interesante y útil análisis. Me gusta la distinción inicial que haces y cómo construyes después.